# How do I keep track of payments to multiple address

Tags: stellar-core, transactions, event-stream

To track the payments we can use streaming API is good solution. [already answered](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/136/how-do-i-keep-track-of-payments-to-an-address-with-js-sdk).

In my case I have a master account(M) as well sub-master(SM) account, I need to have multiple sub-master(SM) accounts.

the process is like when a user trusts `MyAsset` and buy `MyTokens` on DEX and now and in return gets `MyTokens`.

With these tokens, the user will now trade with `sub-master(SM)` accounts

so I need to track the payment of `MyAsset` on `sub-master` account

as I have multiple `sub-master` accounts possibly `15-20`

I need to track `received transaction` on each and every `sub-master(SM)` account.

Note: Master account does not have `Secret Keys of Sub-Master account`.

As a master account owner ,now I need to perform some operations when the user sends `mytoken` to `sub-master` account.

**is it possible to achieve in a single job without watching separately all the sub-master accounts?**

Answer (score 2):

Check [StellarNotifier](https://github.com/orbitlens/stellar-notifier), a standalone service that tracks all operations for the unlimited number of accounts using a single Horizon stream. I made it as flexible as possible to simplify standard pub-sub tasks of tracking multiple update streams for anchors and payments processors.

You can dynamically create subscriptions with guaranteed delivery to track specific accounts, assets, operations types.

Comment: I followed all the steps and now doing ** npm run test**.

 the test fails with this error;
1.expects valid maxSize argument:
2.evicts old entries when the limit is reached:

Comment: I think this is the correct approach. I have a similar project that pushes to GCP Pub/Sub and uses cloud functions to process the events.

Answer (score 0):

not very optimized answer but this will watch payment on both the accounts.

```
app.get("stream", function (req, res) {
    let funding_account1 = issuer.publicKey // This needs to be a valid account on the network and should return an Account object
    let stream = server.payments()
        .forAccount(funding_account1)
        .cursor('now')
        .stream({
            onmessage: function (message) {
                if ((message.type == "create_account") || (message.type == "payment")) {
                    var details = "from:" + message.from + ",to:" + message.to + ",amount:" + message.amount;
                    console.log(details)
                    // Set your own code after we find our create account event
                    stream()
                }
            }
        })
    let stream2 = server.payments()
        .forAccount(funding_account2.publicKey)
        .cursor('now')
        .stream({
            onmessage: function (message) {
                if ((message.type == "create_account") || (message.type == "payment")) {

                    var details = "from:" + message.from + ",to:" + message.to + ",amount:" + message.amount;
                    console.log(details)
                    // Set your own code after we find our create account event
                    stream()
               }
            }
        })
})
```